# Get .txt files in subfolders and name it with folder name

Tags: bash, shell

```
folder
     |___subfolder
             |_____file.txt
     |
     |___subfolder
             |____subfolder
                      |_______file.txt
     etc
```

I have a folder that looks like this. I want to get all the .txt files but as they all have the same name I also want to add the folder name in front of file.txt.

```
do
    name_folder= $(basename $folder)
    echo $name_folder
    for subfolder in $folder;
    do
    find .*txt
    done;
done;
```

I expect $(foldername)basename_txt but this way I am only getting the .txt files

Comment: As an aside, the space after `name_folder=` causes it to do quite something different than you are probably hoping for (which would most likely cause a `command not found` error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
folder=$(echo "${PWD##*/}") #assuming you need only folder name, not full path

# find way from Secespitus
find . -name "*.txt" | while read line
# for each line, using sed adding folder name after last use of character "/"
#then renaming
do mv $(echo $line) $(echo $line | sed "s/\(.*\)\//\1\/$folder/")
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `find` command to get the name with the full path to every .txt file.

`find . -name "*.txt"`

will print out:

```
./test/subdir/file.txt
./test/subdir2/subdir/file.txt
```

If you need the full path you can use that instead of `.` in the `find` command:

`find /home/someone/ -name "*.txt"`

will yield:

```
/home/someone/test/subdir/file.txt
/home/someone/test/subdir2/subdir/file.txt
```

And if you need only the last directory you can pipe the output of the `find` command into `sed`:

`find /home/someone/ -name "*.txt" | sed 's/.*\/\(.*\/.*txt\)/\1/g'`

will yield:

```
subdir/file.txt
subdir/file.txt
```

Comment: It's not clear what the OP's `do` loops over (as posted, it's a syntax error) but maybe mention `find folder otherfolder third etc -name '*.txt'` to run a single `find` in a number of directories.

Comment: thank you this works find and if i want to install these files I use get instead of find ?

Comment: @oezlem That probably depends on your installation method. I am not sure what you are trying to install there as your question here is about finding text files. Do these files include statements to install stuff? Are the file names equivalent to package names you want to install? Are these RPM's instead of text files? I suggest you experiment a bit with your package manager and your preferred method of installing things and if you are having problems you can ask another question here on StackOverflow with more details about how you are trying to install things, what OS you have , ...

Comment: @oezlem You might also be interested in [Unix & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) for your questions. And if this answer answered the question you asked you can click on the little checkmark to accept it and show others that you have found a solution to your problem.